# SQL Server : left outer joins and return Y or N if a value exists

Tags: sql-server, join, unique, case, max

I have a query that is displaying a bunch of information on persons and whether or not they've ever had the existence of a group of dxcodes.  Each column is a different check for another group of dxcodes in the same table:

example output:

```
pid . . . .HTN . . .DM  
123 . . . Y . . . . .N  
456 . . . N . . . . .N
```

Query:

```
select  
    p.pid
    ,CASE WHEN HTN.pid is not null THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS HTN   
    ,... (other case statements)
from p

left outer join (  
    SELECT dx.pid, max(create_timestamp) as maxdate  
    FROM pdx  
    WHERE pdx.dxcode IN ('401','401.0','401.1','401.9')  
    group by dx.pid  
    ) as HTN on p.pid = HTN.pid
```

...other joins on same pdx table to query for other dx codes existence

My query works but I don't think it's as efficient as it could be. I really don't need the maxdate for anything but it worked.  Prior to this I was using select distinct person but realized how much post-processing it had to do and the query performance is already dramatically better. For best practice I think the additional computation by using max to return only one result is still an unnecessary computation.

I tried using variations of exists, left joins, top 1 1 and case statements to do the same thing but I'm just not executing the code properly.

Thanks. I know this has to be an easy answer. The terms I've been searching for just haven't yielded the answer I was hoping for.

Comment: Nice Q - from what I can see, the `max()` seems to be ignored in the query plan so the nested select is the same as `SELECT pdx.pid .. GROUP BY pdx.pid`. I'm not 100% sure, but I would imagine SQL stops evaluating once it has found at least one diagnosis for that person.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is more efficient, but it looks simpler.

```
SELECT
 p.pid,
 MAX(CASE WHEN pdx.dxcode IN ('401','401.0','401.1','401.9') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS HTN,
 MAX(CASE WHEN pdx.dxcode IN ('501','501.0','501.1','501.9') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS DM,
 MAX(CASE WHEN pdx.dxcode IN ('601') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS XN
FROM p
LEFT OUTER JOIN pdx ON p.pid = pdx.pid
GROUP BY
 p.pid
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/118c8/1)

**UPDATE:**

If you are looking to get rid of the MAX so that it stops at the first instance of a positive match, then try this.

```
SELECT
 DISTINCT
 p.pid,
 CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pdx WHERE p.pid = pdx.pid AND pdx.dxcode IN ('401','401.0','401.1','401.9')) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS HTN,
 CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pdx WHERE p.pid = pdx.pid AND pdx.dxcode IN ('501','501.0','501.1','501.9')) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS DM,
 CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pdx WHERE p.pid = pdx.pid AND pdx.dxcode IN ('601')) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS XN
FROM p
;
```

You can try this which will get the distinct pid first then find the first positive match for each one.

```
WITH pd AS (SELECT DISTINCT p.pid FROM p)
SELECT
 pd.pid,
 CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pdx WHERE pd.pid = pdx.pid AND pdx.dxcode IN ('401','401.0','401.1','401.9')) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS HTN,
 CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pdx WHERE pd.pid = pdx.pid AND pdx.dxcode IN ('501','501.0','501.1','501.9')) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS DM,
 CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pdx WHERE pd.pid = pdx.pid AND pdx.dxcode IN ('601')) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS XN
FROM pd 
GROUP BY
 pd.pid
;
```

[SQL Fiddle for those 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/118c8/14)

Comment: the thing with all 3 of our examples is they use max or sum.  There's got to be a way to do it without a calculation that requires complete review of the table.  I only assume top or exist stops at the first occurrence.  I do like you're design because it's definitely cleaner.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a couple more examples that may help. Of course, you'll have to test them against your data set to see how well they actually do.

Comment: +1 - although the updated answer can be simplified, assuming p.pid is a primary key, since we no longer join to pdx in the outer loop, the distinct and group can be removed. Updated SqlFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/118c8/20 Strangely enough, SqlFiddle's plans indicate that these 4 queries all have the same query plan, with a cost of .0144, i.e. no real improvement on the original query, other than improved readability.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe change your CASE statements to something like WHEN HTN.pid IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, sum each case, then wrap a final SELECT around the whole thing?  Then, for example, when HTN > 0 THEN Y ELSE N?

```
select
    pid,
    case when HTN > 0 then 'Y' else 'N' end AS 'HTN',
    case when DM > 0 then 'Y' else 'N' end AS 'DM',
    case when CBG > 0 then 'Y' else 'N' end AS 'CBG',
    case when XYZ > 0 then 'Y' else 'N' end AS 'XYZ',
    case when DB > 0 then 'Y' else 'N' end AS 'DB'
from (  
        select
            p.pid,
            sum(case when pdx.dxcode in ('409', '409.1', '409.3') then 1 else 0 end) as 'HTN',
            sum(case when pdx.dxcode in ('899', '899.1', '892.2') then 1 else 0 end) as 'DM',
            sum(case when pdx.dxcode in ('410.0', '419.1', '419.3') then 1 else 0 end) as 'CBG',
            sum(case when pdx.dxcode in ('250', '250.1', '250.3') then 1 else 0 end) as 'XYZ',
            sum(case when pdx.dxcode in ('58.0', '58.1', '58.3') then 1 else 0 end) as 'DB'
        from
            person p left join
            pdx on
                p.pid = pdx.pid
        group by p.pid
    ) as dx
```

Comment: the thing with all 3 of our examples is they use max or sum.  There's got to be a way to do it without a calculation that requires complete review of the table.  I only assume top or exist stops at the first occurrence.  I'm thinking yours would be slightly quicker as it's summed it up as it processes the table and wouldn't result in a temp table (a guess).

It's funny because they both are pretty efficient.  My guess is yours would be a little quicker.